# SVG For Image Masking In IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, mask

Im using IE 10 here, firefox works fine, but no mask is showing in IE

```
<svg style="height:0;">
                                      <mask id="m1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                                        <image width="78px" height="78px" xlink:href="images/mask2.png"></image>
                                      </mask>
                                    </svg>
                                    <img src="images/avatar-sample.jpg" style="mask:url(#m1);"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG Image Mask Not Working In Firefox or IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320863/svg-image-mask-not-working-in-firefox-or-ie)

Comment: Pretty similar but in one the mask is applied to a foreignObject and in the other to a HTML img element. The former should work in IE but not the latter.

Comment: neither work in ie. the former using foreignObject shows completely blank page in IE

Answer (score 0):

Only Firefox currently supports [applying a mask directly to an HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example%3a.C2.A0Masking). Other UAs only allow you to set an SVG effect such as a mask on an SVG object.

If you want this to work in IE you'll have to use an SVG `<image>` element to display the image rather than a HTML `<img>` element.

Comment: so has anyone got any comments on how to make this work in both FF and IE?

Comment: That's your other question. I've answered this one.